# Java: Adding a row of JCombobox in a AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox, abstracttablemodel

I am trying to make a row which will contain `JCombobox` in a class which extends `AbstractTableModel`.

I have a 2D array which is called data. I also use the method `getColumnCount()` in order to implement two buttons "Previous" and "Next". I have marked where I think the `JCombobox` should be, but I don't know how I should implement in the whole row.

```
public class SwitchTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // Standard number of rows
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // Number of columns change according to the data
        return data [position].length + 1;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (rowIndex)
        {
        case 0:
            return columnIndex == 0 ? "ID" : idArray [data [position][columnIndex - 1]];
        case 1:
            return columnIndex == 0 ? "Company Name" : company_nameArray [data [position][columnIndex - 1]];
        case 2: 
            return columnIndex == 0 ? "Double" : ...???
        default:
            throw new Error ();
        }
    }

    public void previous ()
    {
        position -= 1;
        if (position < 0) position = data.length - 1;

        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public void next ()
    {
        position += 1;
        if (position >= data.length) position = 0;

        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
}
```

Any help will be valuable

Comment: have to re_wrote AbstracttableModel too, in my profile are code example including AutoComplete JComboBox as XxxTableCellEditor, use that for edit your question and to post an SSCCE, otherwise everything there are shorts to the dark

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't find the code example:(

Comment: Read the JTable API and then follow the link to the Swing tutorial titled "How to Use Tables" for an example of a table containing a combo box.

Comment: @Dimitra Micha `I am sorry, I couldn't find the code example`, sure without reading the tutorial is required to bothering little bit more [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+jtable+jcombobox) or [my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+[jtable]+[jcombobox]), again without posting an SSCCE this question isn't answerable at all

Answer (score 2):

> Adding a row of JCombobox in a AbstractTableModel,

- this is wrong idea, `XxxTableModel` hold only last selected (or intialized on 1st use) value in `String form` (in the case that `XxxComboBoxModel` contains Item in String form, if is there Number, then model contains only one munber)
- have to split `JComboBox as Editor` an `XxxTableModel`, then this idea works
- do not put `JComboBox` to the `XxxTableModel`, follows code example from Oracle tutorial

Comment: +1 correct for separation of model and editor. Maybe override `prepareEditor()` for a specific row?

Comment: @trashgod hehehe agreed, but this is very specific question (-:shot to the dark:-)???,